# How can I convert a time zone offset abbreviation to the official time zone identifier?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

When I call *[NSTimeZone’s](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTimeZone)* abbreviation method it returns `GMT-07:00`. Then, when I use this value to lookup the time zone name or ([**time zone identifier**](http://www.w3.org/TR/timezone/#tzids)) it returns `nil`.

I need to retrieve the official [time zone identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/timezone/#tzids), e.g., `America/Los_Angeles`. Therefore, how can I convert a time zone offset abbreviation (e.g., `GMT-07:00`) to the official time zone identifier?

Here’s my code:

```
NSTimeZone* localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSString* localAbbreviation = [localTimeZone abbreviation];
NSDictionary* abbreviationDictionary = [NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary];
NSString* timeZoneID = 
[abbreviationDictionary objectForKey:localAbbreviation]; //should return 'America/Los_Angeles' if the abbreviation is ‘PDT’
```

Comment: This is not possible in my opinion. There exist many more than 24 time zones. An exact mapping of time zone offset to an actual time zone is impossible.

Comment: By the way, calling `[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] abbreviation]` in my locale/location returns `@"CEST"` and not a numeric offset.

Comment: Thanks Ole, I’m getting GMT—07:00, which is an invalid local time zone abbreviation.

Comment: Well, there is no exact mapping between abbreviations and actual time zones. Different countries or regions use the same abbreviation for entirely different time zones. I don't know how the system decides what to return as the "abbreviation" but your code has to take into account that it can never be perfect.

Comment: You're right, it looks like the framework does not support my case. I would have to create a database that would map the GMT offset to the correct time zone identifier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(I rewrote my reply, I misunderstood the question before).*

Here's an example on how to convert a timeZone from the abbreviation:

```
NSTimeZone* localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSString* localAbbreviation = [localTimeZone abbreviation];
```

To transform it back from the localAbbreviation, is just a matter to re-create the timeZone:

```
NSTimeZone* timeZoneFromAbbreviation = [NStimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:abbreviation];
NSString* timeZoneIdentifier = timeZoneAbbreviation.name;

NSLog(@"Identifier: %@", timeZoneIdentifier); // Outputs America/Santiago for me.
```

Are you sure the abbreviation is returning "GMT-07:00"? Mine returns "CLT", not a GMT offset.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work when the value of the local time zone is expressed as a GMT offset. When call NSTimeZone’s description method I get the following: Local Time Zone (Etc/GMT+7 (GMT-07:00) offset -25200)

Comment: Weird, it should be returning "PST", in fact, looking at the contents of the dictionary (`NSLog(@"timeZone: %@", [NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]);`), `America/Los_Angeles` is registered, yet the localTimeZone returns the wrong abbreviation... I'm gonna try changing the date on my iPhone.

Comment: Ok, I changed the Time Zone in my iPhone to "America/Los Angeles", and the abbreviation code works normally (`Identifier: America/Los_Angeles`). Sorry, I can't replicate the issue. If it helps, my `timeZoneDataVersion` returns "2010o".

Comment: Yeah, your code should work. However, if the abbreviation is a GMT offset like GMT-07:00, the time zone name is invalid.

Comment: Nope, GMT -07:00 is not Incorrect, for the timezone like in case of the India, It returns GMT 07:30 instead of IST

Answer (score 2):

Hope this might be helpful
Edit The + should be there to show exactly as normal Abbreviation

```
   -(NSString*)getTimeZoneStringForAbbriviation:(NSString*)abbr{
        NSTimeZone *atimezone=[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:abbr];
        int minutes = (atimezone.secondsFromGMT / 60) % 60;
        int hours = atimezone.secondsFromGMT / 3600;
        NSString *aStrOffset=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",hours, minutes];
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GMT+%@",aStrOffset];
    }
```

Comment: excellent answer with good calcualations and please add + in stringWithFormat

Comment: Will putting "+" in your format string work for zones that are negative from GMT? Such as GMT-7:00.  It might be better to put + in the first format string:  stringWithFormat:@"%+02d:%02d"   That will cause stringWithFormat to add the + if the number is positive.   (The example above might add a '-' to the minutes as well for negative GMT offsets.)

Comment: Thank you Ashok, but actually + is not for all Timezones. So it can not be there hardcoded, what you say ? I think i need to put something in code.So i am also agree with @WaltSellers.